# Achieve the same satellite view as Android Maps application using Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to reproduce the same satellite view as the Google Maps application on Android.

This is a picture of the satellite view (it shows the main streets/roads highlighted) in Maps application: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCkLL.png

But using the layers of the Google Maps API i can not achieve the same result.

I want to show the main street/routes roads highlighted like the Maps application. I search all the possible options but i did not found nothing that fit my needs.

Is there is something i am missing? Or i have to develop a new layer to show the roads like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

did you try to use the "HYBRID" map type?

```
myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
```

it should fix your problem

Comment: Hi, yes i tried to use GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID. But it is not has the same effect as the Maps app.

Here is a picture of the hybrid: http://imgur.com/ErZh2wy.

If you compare it to the one i attached in the first place, the roads/main streets are not highlighted.

Comment: So it seems they use another service for that... For sure you cant use the same :/